# Accessing HttpServletResponse from AOP advice (in @After annotation) in Spring 2.5 with annotations

Tags: spring-aop

I have tried to find the answer to this question. I have found a lot of pages describing horrible architectures and asking for about the same thing as I do, but my intended usage is different so please bear with me :-)

```java
@After(value = "@annotation(test.Customannotation) && @annotation(custom)", argNames="custom")
public void increaseCounter(Customannotation custom){
        // Here I want HttpServeletResponse
}
```

I have used below code to get but it isn't working

```java
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
ServletWebRequest servletWebRequest=new ServletWebRequest(request);
HttpServletResponse response=servletWebRequest.getResponse(); // it is coming as null
```

I have tried

```java
@Autowired
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;
```

but seems it is also not working. httpServletResponse.getStatus() is returning 200 but the actual response returned by an api is 208.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please edit your question, adding a full aspect class with package name, imports and annotations. Then do the same around your incoherent code snippets. The Spring configuration would also be helpful. BTW, "isn't working" is not a very helpful error description, and it is completely unclear what is returning which HTTP status where, as your example is not an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read). Your pointcut `@annotation(test.Customannotation) && @annotation(custom)` also looks strange. Why the same thing twice?

Comment: _(continued)_ Maybe you should not complain about "pages describing horrible architectures" either without providing references to them and explaining what in particular is so horrible about them. And you should not throw stones out from within a glass house, not even being willing or able to write your question in such a way as to make the problem both understandable and reproducible.